# Change android textview color with number picker Integer

Tags: java, android, textview

I am new to android and I am just dipping my toes in with is. I want to have number picker define what the color of text is. This is the code for the number picker so far.

```
package nathan.nathan;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView numberView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        numberView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numberview);
        NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(100);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener( new NumberPicker.
            OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int
                oldVal, int newVal) {
            numberView.setText("I am "+
                    newVal);
        }

    });
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I'm just confused on what to do. Help would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to you how you'd like to map your integer from 0 to 100 to a color, but here's one way to do it:

```
numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(
    new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        numberView.setText("I am " + newVal);

        int color;
        if (newVal < 30) {
            color = Color.parseColor("#ff0000");
        } else if (newVal < 60) {
            color = Color.parseColor("#00ff00");
        } else {
            color = Color.parseColor("#0000ff");
        }
        numberView.setTextColor(color);
    }
});
```

See the [TextView.setTextColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(int)) documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't want to complain or anything but is there a way to change the color value automatically?

Comment: No problem! What do you mean by "automatically"? With the `NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener`, `onValueChange()` will be called every time the number changes, which will will change the color.

Comment: I ment not having to write all of the colors I wish to use.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve. e.g. you could set your spinner to have a range of integers from 0 to 255, then use `Color.argb(255, newVal, 0, 0)`, which will return a brighter red when `newVal` is greater.